# How to restrict the access/activation times for a service/socket with systemd?

Tags: systemd, services, socket, access-control, socket-activation

I have a simple systemd service that is activated by system socket.

It's as simple as that (a little simplified):

```
$ systemctl cat example.socket 
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/example.socket
[Unit]
Description=Example Server socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=80
Accept=true

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
$ systemctl cat example@.service 
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/example@.service
[Unit]
Description=Example Server

[Service]
StandardInput=socket
StandardOutput=socket
StandardError=journal
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/example
User=example
```

Now what I want is to implement a basic **access restriction** by time. I.e. I want to limit the time a day the socket/service can be activated/reached from the outside, so it's only available at certain times a day, e.g.

I know I can use `systemctl edit` to override the options, but I did not found an option to set, actually. [I looked through the man page regarding system sockets](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd/systemd.socket.5.en.html) and the only options regarding times are `TriggerLimitIntervalSec` or so, which do not do what I want.

To compare this, the little oldish tool `xinetdx`, which can do the same i.e. listen on a socket and start a process (server) on demand [has an option](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/doc/redhat/redhat8/rhl-rg-en-8.0/s1-tcpwrappers-xinetd.html) called `access_times`, which can be used to specify when a service should be available.
But using this as another tool (/dependency) is not a thing I'd like. I'd aim for an integrated way into systemd.

Comment: As a completely alternate solution you could use a firewall rule. There does exist a match that compares the time of day with some values both in iptables and nftables.

Comment: have you considered using a cron job to stop and start the service at the required times?

Comment: @cas It's a socket. and I want to use socket activation. Maybe I could though enable/disable the socket at the required times, but I'm not sure whether that is the most elegant solution – considering e.g. what happens if the device is down at the time and only start later or so. But if you want to submit this as an answer, feel free to do so.

Comment: @A.B Yeah good idea, but I use `firewall-cmd` (Fedora system), and as far as I see it does not support that and so resorting to some lower-level tool for that is well… maybe not so nice, yet again.

Comment: firewalld doesn't have to support it: *nftables* can use separate tables (eg: firewalld chooses its own `firewalld` table) and when a packet is dropped it won't come back. Anyway that was a suggestion, I'm not trying to convince.

Comment: Yeah thanks, it's a good suggestion, but actually I'm still looking for something better.

Comment: Given there does not seem to be a built-in way in systemd, I [raised a feature request](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/19620).

Comment: @rugk yes, it's a socket.  systemd can still start and stop listening on that port with `systemctl start example.socket` and `systemctl stop example.socket`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some [systemd timers](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) to start/stop the socket at the required times.

To wakeup `mysocket.socket` every morning at 06:00 and put it to bed at 23:00 every night try this:

```
# mysocket.timer
[Unit]
Description=Socket Wakeup

[Timer]
OnCalendar=6:00
Unit=mysocket.socket

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

```
# mysocket-bedtime.timer
[Unit]
Description=Socket Bedtime

[Timer]
OnCalendar=23:00
Unit=mysocket-bedtime.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

```
# mysocket-bedtime.service
[Unit]
Description=MySocket bedtime enforcer
Conflicts=mysocket.socket

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
```

`mysocket.timer` is pretty straight forward.  It start `Unit=mysocket.socket` at 06:00 every morning.  Stopping your socket is a little more difficult.  It requires a `Conflicts=` relationship.  We create `mysocket-bedtime.timer` to wake up that conflicting unit at 23:00 every night.  `mysocket-bedtime.service` is that conflicting unit.  For it to start, it will shut down anything it `Conflicts=` with (your socket). Then when your socket has stopped, it simply executes `true` and then stops itself.

Comment: Okay, nice one. But (how) is this better than just having two timers running `systemctl start/stop example.socket` or so manually?

Comment: Well, if you were to do that, you'd need `mysocket-wakeup.timer` with `mysocket-wakeup.service` and `mysocket-sleep.timer` with `mysocket-sleep.service`.  This solution uses one fewer units.  Also, you are using native systemd unit relationships instead of `systemctl`.  The native systemd relationships are designed for these situations and probably cover some edge cases better than using `systemctl` (which is not really designed to be invoked from a service). Finally, this is what the devs recommended when they closed your feature request.